# How to add event listener to Gifdecoder in Libgdx?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I asked this [question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/136659/is-it-possible-to-use-animated-gif-images-in-lbgdx/136661#136661) and implemented the accepted answer. One last piece of the puzzle remains, how to add event listener to the button?

I'm working with a teammate, I suggested to try `Gdx.input.justTouched()` but he wonders if it's possible to add event listeners like you would do for normal buttons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to achieve this could be to extend the existing `Button` class and provide an implementation that sets the `up`, `down`, `checked` and `disabled` `Drawable`s of the `ButtonStyle` to whatever the last key-frame of the animation loaded is.

That way you'd get standard button behavior and the only thing that changes is the (somewhat weird) continuously updating style.

Such a `Button` might look something like this;
    package com.bornander.sandbox;

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Animation;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureRegion;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Button;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.utils.TextureRegionDrawable;

public class AnimatedButton extends Button {

    private float elapsed;
    // Technically you'll need one of these for each state of the ButtonStyle, but I'll just cover up and down here.
    private final Animation<TextureRegion> upAnimation;
    private final Animation<TextureRegion> downAnimation;
    private final ButtonStyle overrideStyle = new ButtonStyle();
    private final TextureRegionDrawable upDrawable = new TextureRegionDrawable();
    private final TextureRegionDrawable downDrawable = new TextureRegionDrawable();

    public AnimatedButton(Animation<TextureRegion> upAnimation, Animation<TextureRegion> downAnimation) {
         this.upAnimation = upAnimation;
         this.downAnimation = downAnimation;
    }

    @Override
    public void act(float delta) {
        super.act(delta);
        elapsed += delta;

        upDrawable.setRegion(upAnimation.getKeyFrame(elapsed));
        downDrawable.setRegion(downAnimation.getKeyFrame(elapsed));
        overrideStyle.up = upDrawable;
        overrideStyle.down = downDrawable;

        setStyle(overrideStyle);
    }
}
```

And it would be instantiated with a list of animations (possibly created using a `GifDecoder`) for each state. Then it is possible to add listeners for clicked just like any other button owned by a `Stage`;

```
package com.bornander.sandbox;

import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationAdapter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Animation;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureRegion;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.InputEvent;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Stage;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Button;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.utils.ClickListener;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.viewport.ScreenViewport;
import com.holidaystudios.tools.GifDecoder;

public class SandboxGame extends ApplicationAdapter {

    Stage stage;

    @Override
    public void create () {
        stage = new Stage(new ScreenViewport());

        Animation<TextureRegion> upAnimation = GifDecoder.loadGIFAnimation(Animation.PlayMode.LOOP, Gdx.files.internal("throbber.gif").read());
        Animation<TextureRegion> downAnimation = GifDecoder.loadGIFAnimation(Animation.PlayMode.LOOP, Gdx.files.internal("throbber.gif").read());
        // Instanciate an AnimatedButton, providing animations for up and down states
        Button button = new AnimatedButton(upAnimation, downAnimation);

        button.setPosition(100, 100);
        button.setSize(32, 32);

        // Here the click listener is added by passing an anonymous type
        button.addListener(new ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
                super.clicked(event, x, y);

                //Add click handler here!

            }
        });

        // Add the button to the Stage
        stage.addActor(button);

        // And set the processor of input to be that stage
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
    }

    @Override
    public void render () {
        // Make sure to update the state of the stage
        stage.act(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 0);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        // Draw the state of the stage
        stage.draw();
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose () {
    }
}
```